# Pickle EOFError: Ran out of input, file is not empty

Tags: python, pickle, eof

The code worked before and suddenly stopped working, throwing "EOFError: Ran out of input" when trying to load my "datei". I suppose at one point the program crashed and the file somehow got corrupted while saving, is that possible? Also the file got quite big, over 300 MB, maybe that also might be a problem? Is there any way to recover the file?

My script / workflow looks like this:

```
def save(datei, objekt):
    f = open(datei, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(objekt, f)
    f.close()
    return 1
def load(datei):
    f = open(datei, 'rb')
    objekt = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return(objekt)

# load data
data = load("datei")

# modify data
# ...

# save the modified data
save("datei", data)
```

Comment: can you share the `datei` file?

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi I would love to, how do I do it?

Comment: paste the information of `datei` on pastebin and share the link here. the original `datei`, not the big one

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ld6fXzrp I opened with notepad and pasted the first few lines, pasting the whole thing did not work, hope thats sufficient

Comment: nah, it didn't help. From your code, my guess is when you're writing the pickle file you should also add the extension in the file name. probably thats why it was corrupted

Comment: yeah that might be it, thank you